# Read SAS file with pandas

Tags: python, pandas, sas

I'm trying to use the pandas `read_sas()` function.

First, I create a SAS dataset by running this code in SAS:

```
libname tmp 'c:\temp';  
data tmp.test;
    do i=1 to 100;
        x=rannor(0);
        output;
    end;
run;
```

Now, in IPython, I do this:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

%cd C:\temp
pd.read_sas('test.sas7bdat')
```

Pretty straightforward and seems like it should work. But I just get this error:

```
TypeError: read() takes at most 1 argument (2 given)
```

What am I missing here? I'm using pandas version `0.18.0`.

Comment: Hmm... I'm getting same problem.  I'm running on windows at the moment.  What OS for you?

Comment: I get the same error on Windows 10 and Linux.

Comment: Looks like a known issue: see [this link](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/12647)

Answer (score 1):

According issue report linked below, this bug will be fixed in 18.1.

https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/12647