# extract a casout SAS table to pandas dataframe

Tags: sas

I am using python API of SAS, and have uploaded a table by:

```
s.upload("./data/hmeq.csv", casout=dict(name=tbl_name, replace=True))
```

I can see the details of the table by `s.tableinfo()`.

```
§ TableInfo
    Name    Rows    Columns IndexedColumns  Encoding    CreateTimeFormatted ModTimeFormatted    AccessTimeFormatted JavaCharSet CreateTime  ... Repeated    View    MultiPart   SourceName  SourceCaslib    Compressed  Creator Modifier    SourceModTimeFormatted  SourceModTime
0   HMEQ    5960    13  0   utf-8   2020-02-10T16:48:02-05:00   2020-02-10T16:48:02-05:00   2020-02-10T21:10:34-05:00   UTF8    1.896990e+09    ... 0   0   0           0   aforoo      2020-02-10T16:48:02-05:00   1.896990e+09
1 rows × 23 columns
```

But, I cannot access any value of the table in python. For example, assume I want to get the number of rows and columns as a python scalar. I know that I can get the SAS tables into `pandas` tables by using `pd.DataFrame`, but it does not work for this table and I get:

```
~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py in __init__(self, data, index, columns, dtype, copy)
    346                                  dtype=dtype, copy=copy)
    347         elif isinstance(data, dict):
--> 348             mgr = self._init_dict(data, index, columns, dtype=dtype)
    349         elif isinstance(data, ma.MaskedArray):
    350             import numpy.ma.mrecords as mrecords

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py in _init_dict(self, data, index, columns, dtype)
    457             arrays = [data[k] for k in keys]
    458 
--> 459         return _arrays_to_mgr(arrays, data_names, index, columns, dtype=dtype)
    460 
    461     def _init_ndarray(self, values, index, columns, dtype=None, copy=False):

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py in _arrays_to_mgr(arrays, arr_names, index, columns, dtype)
   7354     # figure out the index, if necessary
   7355     if index is None:
-> 7356         index = extract_index(arrays)
   7357 
   7358     # don't force copy because getting jammed in an ndarray anyway

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py in extract_index(data)
   7391 
   7392         if not indexes and not raw_lengths:
-> 7393             raise ValueError('If using all scalar values, you must pass'
   7394                              ' an index')
   7395 

ValueError: If using all scalar values, you must pass an index
```

I have same issue with any other `casout` table in SAS. I appreciate any help or comment.

Comment: What python api of SAS?  Are you talking about saspy?

Comment: Since your results and tables are in CAS, you probably need to download the results to your client to read into a dataframe. I'm not very familiar with SWAT yet, but there is probably an additional function that does this. https://go.documentation.sas.com/?docsetId=caspg3&docsetTarget=n1jtz4vzlaba8kn1dzligjukyk57.htm&docsetVersion=3.2&locale=en

Comment: @Tom, in any cas-based API, when I fetch a `casout` table result, I have this problem. For example, consider `casout = dict(name = 'out1', replace=True)` which is used in `sdataSciencePilot.exploreData(table=tbl_name, target='bad', casout=casout)`  in which `s` is an instance of `swat.CAS(server, port)`.

Comment: @Tom, also I have the example in the question about the `s.tableinfo()` which is a `swat.cas.results.CASResults` table.

Comment: @Tom, I found and added a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution below and it works fine. For example, here I have used `dataSciencePilot.exploreData` action and I can get the results by:

```
casout = dict(name = 'out1', replace=True)
s.dataSciencePilot.exploreData(table=tbl_name, target='bad', casout=casout)
fetch_opts = dict(maxrows=100000000, to=1000000)
df = s.fetch(table='out1', **fetch_opts)['Fetch']
features = pd.DataFrame(df)
type(features)
```

which returns `pandas.core.frame.DataFrame`.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you use directly Pandas to read from SAS.

Reference from another answer: [Read SAS file with pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36310319/read-sas-file-with-pandas)

Here is another example
https://www.marsja.se/how-to-read-sas-files-in-python-with-pandas/

Comment: This would work if his data was local, but it is in a distributed computing environment called CAS. All processing is being done there.

Comment: I have not saved the data and as @StuSztukowski mentioned the data is in memory.

Comment: @StuSztukowski, I found a solution and posted it, so that it might be helpful for other people.